# PhoneGap app (for apple) doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am new to phonegap and coding so I am unaware as to how to use PhoneGap. First of all what I did was connect my PhoneGap (desktop) app thing to my iPhone PhoneGap developers app. On my iPhone it just says `downloading...` there is nothing else happening. I then tried using an Android phone to see if it works but it just says

```
unable to download archive from the server.
unable to properly connect to the server.
```

I dont know what to do so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be caused by many things.**

I assume you followed the steps from http://app.phonegap.com/ site:

- you have created a phonegap app (at least a sample one using '*phonegap create*')
- you have a server running (using phonegap desktop or '*phonegap serve*' from command line)

There are some things you have to check in order to know what is wrong:

1. Both the devices must be in the same network to 'see' each other.
2. The firewall is turned off or allows communication on the port the server is running on (default is port 3000)
3. Check if your antivirus isn't blocking the same port.

If you still have no connection [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/307) is the survey/checklist you should go through. It helps you get closer to the center of the problem you have (points: 7-11).

If that does not help you can always fill an issue (and attach above-mentioned survey) but I **strongly recommend reading documentation first**